# Installing a package available which was available in an older release

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, 22.04

I would like to install `liblog4cxx-dev` at version 0.10 which was available in Ubuntu 20.04. However, I have moved on to Ubuntu 22.04 and intend to stay there, and the only version available is 0.12 which is causing build issues.

I want to install 0.10 version via apt

Is there any way I could do this ?

TIA

Comment: helpful? https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/liblog4c-dev_1.2.4-2_amd64.deb.html

Comment: Yes, Got the package I needed from here, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package required should be available from this Ubuntu Universe resource for v22.04:

https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/22.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/liblog4c-dev_1.2.4-2_amd64.deb.html